# Hibernate. How to map own class as type of property in entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

How  to map with Hibernate my own class as type of property in other class? For example I have class **Address** and class **User**. And I try to map as following:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private Address address;
    // other fields
}
```

But I get the exception in this case:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: es.myproject.entity.User
```

I would be grateful for any guidance or useful links on the respective samples. Preferably using Hibernate annotations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add annotations stating the relationship between the two entities, such as `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany`.

Probably something like:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
    private Address address;
    // other fields
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in to these [tutorials](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/)